# Как залогировать всю работу в командной строке Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, командная-строка, windows-11

Есть необходимость залогировать абсолютно всё, что отображается в командной строке, и ввод команд и их вывод. Подразумевается задокументировать работу через ssh.
Операторы перенаправления `>` и `>>` не подходят, т.к. вывод также необходимо отображать в командной строке.

Вообще достаточно будет записать `ssh <uset>@<ip>`. Пытался делать с помощью `2>&1 > a.txt & type a.txt`. Но в таком случае максимум, что отображалось в командной строке, так это ввод пароля. В остальном — пустота, пока процесс не остановится.

Банальное копировать и вставить меня не устраивает, т.к. искренне надеюсь, что windows предусмотрен необходимый мне функционал.

Comment: Это для себя? или вообще? или ещё и при активном противодействии оператора?

Comment: Есть проект https://asciinema.org, но он под linux. Хотя у тебя там ssh, так что проблем особых не вижу. Ты же не собираешься это делать скрыто?

Comment: Это одна из функций продуктов, предназначенных для контроля за действиями привилегированных пользователей: Privileged access management (PAM). Естественно, это - коммерческие решения. Где-то находил решения на базе Opensource (по принципу прокси).

Comment: В Винде есть аналог линуксовой команды tee через powershell, видимо нужно туда куда-то копать: powershell -Command "cmd /c script.bat | Tee-Object –file output.log"